How to filter the result of group aggregation in MongoDB?
Here is a collection in MongoDB that contains documents with the following structure:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "663bde27b35e766556ebc60c"
  },
  "email": "diego.latorre@guane.com.co",
  "name": "juan",
  "accessControl": [
    {
      "module": "seguimiento",
      "organization": {
        "$oid": "64591e18c826eb8dec7cff39"
      },
      "role": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "64591e18c826eb8dec7cff3c"
        },
        "name": "owner"
      }
    },
    {
      "module": "observatorio",
      "organization": null,
      "role": {
        "name": "administrator",
        "id": {
          "$oid": "663e3814b35e766556ebc623"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "emailVerified": false,
  "disabled": false
}

(in access control there may be several modules that correspond to different organizations)
I need to make a query to bring all the users belonging to an organization and group them by role
(i.e. I receive the organization id as input).
So, I wrote the following aggregation:
[
  {
    $match: {
      "accessControl.organization": ObjectId(
        "64591e18c826eb8dec7cff39"
      ),
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        role: "$accessControl.role.name",
        id: "$accessControl.role.id",
      },
      users: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          disabled: "$disabled",
          email: "$email",
          emailVerified: "$emailVerified",
          name: "$name",
          accessControl: ["$accessControl"],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      role: "$_id",
      users: 1,
    },
  },
]

My aggregation ALMOST meets the objective, but has the problem that since there are users with more than one module in access control, my result is like this:
{
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "663bde27b35e766556ebc60c"
      },
      "disabled": false,
      "email": "diego.latorre@guane.com.co",
      "emailVerified": false,
      "name": "juan",
      "accessControl": [
        [
          {
            "module": "seguimiento",
            "organization": {
              "$oid": "64591e18c826eb8dec7cff39"
            },
            "role": {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "64591e18c826eb8dec7cff3c"
              },
              "name": "owner"
            }
          },
          {
            "module": "observatorio",
            "organization": null,
            "role": {
              "name": "administrator",
              "id": {
                "$oid": "663e3814b35e766556ebc623"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "role": {
    "role": [
      "owner",
      "administrator"
    ],
    "id": [
      {
        "$oid": "663e3814b35e766556ebc623"
      }
    ]
  }
}

As you can see, in the role section, both "owner" and "administrator" were brought in, but I only need owner to appear, since it is the module in which the organization_id matches.
If I place a first stage with this:
{
    $unwind: "$accessControl",
},

I would get my desired result, but I will have many users so it is not very efficient to unwind. What can I do to be able to obtain only the role of the match match?

you want it filtered out? https://mongoplayground.net/p/LGoVpSIc8od

Yeah! That is what I need!. Do you think I should put the addFields stage before or after the match?

better after the match since it filters out docs in the match stage

Btw, there's a typo in your example data - for the accessControl list, the first entry has role._id but the second entry has role.id - note the missing leading underscore _. So whichever is the correct one, should be used in your pipeline, currently $accessControl.role.id. But if the example is from your database, you will probably need to update to update the original records there.

Thanks for your comments. Maybe I need accessControl not to be an array but an Object. I already saw that I can achieve this with $arrayElemAt in the same stage and taking the index 0. With this in mind, do you think this approach is more efficient than unwind? Or I can only know by doing real tests

i think accessing array element is better than unwind. also instead of arrayElemAt there is also a shorthand $first https://mongoplayground.net/p/rJvS5VUgbEc

@DiegoL if you have found the asnwer maybe you can write here

Sure, I used your comment to solve it.  I will write the answer today or tomorrow.  Thank you.

As recommended in the comments, one approach could be to "override" accessControl with a stage of $addFields:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "accessControl.organization": ObjectId("64591e18c826eb8dec7cff39")
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "accessControl": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$accessControl",
          as: "access",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$access.organization",
              ObjectId("64591e18c826eb8dec7cff39")
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        role: "$accessControl.role.name",
        id: "$accessControl.role.id"
      },
      users: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          disabled: "$disabled",
          email: "$email",
          emailVerified: "$emailVerified",
          name: "$name",
          accessControl: [
            "$accessControl"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      role: "$_id",
      users: 1
    }
  }
])

I did performance tests and at least for my case, this approach is considerably better than unwind
